# Problem rendering large amount of DOM into modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, templates

i have a problem rendering large amount of html into modal javascript. What are best practices for this problem ?.(NO JQuery pls)

My options are (resuming code, just the logic):

```js
fetch('file.hmtl', {
   method: 'GET'
})
.then((data) = {
  return data.text();
})
.then((data) => {
  document.getElementById('modal-body').innertHTML = data
})
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div>Laaaaaargeeeeee amount of html</div>
</div>
```

**or:**

```js
document.getElementById('modal-body').innertHTML = `<div class="modal-wrapper">laaaaargeeee amount of html</div>`
```

didn't put modal/largeHtml example in main index.php with hide property. Because performance and bad practices.

If anyone knows another one solution or best practices for this situation. I will apreciate. Ty

Comment: What type of data you are trying to show on page?  You can use pagination to show contents if there are so many data.

Comment: SignUp and SignIn views